# Save a combobox list into a .txt file

Tags: excel, vba

VBA: Is there a way to save a list of a combobox to a .txt file?

I did this one here that puts the information of a txt file into a combobox

```
Dim InFile As Integer
InFile = FreeFile
Open "MYFILE.txt" For Input As InFile
While Not EOF(InFile)
  Line Input #InFile, NextTip
   ComboBox1.AddItem NextTip
   ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0

Wend
Close InFile
```

Answer (score 1):

The following macro will print a list of items from the specified combobox to the specified text file.  Change the name of the macro, and the path and file name for the destination file, accordingly.

```
    'Force the explict declaration of variables
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        'Declare the variables
        Dim destFile As String
        Dim fileNum As Long
        Dim i As Long

        'Assign the path and file name for the destination file (change accordingly)
        destFile = "C:\Users\Domenic\Desktop\sample.txt"

        'Get the next available file number
        fileNum = FreeFile()

        'Print list items from combobox to destination file
        Open destFile For Output As #fileNum
            With Me.ComboBox1
                For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                    Print #fileNum, .List(i)
                Next i
            End With
        Close #fileNum

        MsgBox "Completed!", vbExclamation

    End Sub
```